# How to find a function describing all possible measures of a countable set?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X$ be a countable set. Define a measure on $X$ as: $$\mu:\mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$$
>
> Such that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and for every disjoint sequence $E_n\subseteq X, n\geq 1$, we have: $$\mu(\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)$$

Find a description of the all possible measures on $X$; that is, show that there exists sets $A$, $B$, and a bijective map from the set of measures on $X$ to $B^A$.

I'm not exactly sure what I should be doing here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu:P(X)\to [0,\infty]$ that means that $$m(\{x\})=a_x\in[0,\infty]$$ for all $x\in X$ since $\{x\}\in P(X)$. But since every set $A\subset X$ can be described as $$A=\bigcup_{x\in A}\{x\}$$

we see that since the right side of that equality is countable sequence of disjoint sets we have $$\mu(A)=\mu(\bigcup_{x\in A}\{x\})=\sum\limits_{x\in A}\mu(x)=\sum\limits_{x\in A}a_x$$

or

$$\mu(A)=\sum\limits_{x\in X} a_x 1_{A}(x)$$

Thus choosing a sequence $\{a_x\}_{x\in X}$ of positive extended real numbers uniquely determines $\mu$.

Comment: What would be set $A$ and $B$ be in this case then?

Comment: $A=[0,\infty]$, $B=X$. $B^A=\{f| f:A\to B\}$ thus $X^{[0,\infty]}=\{f |f: X\to [0,\infty]\}$ in this case another way of writing $f$ is $\{f(x)\}_{x\in X}$ which for all intents and purposes is the same as $\{a_x\}_{x\in X}$ if you imagine that $f(x)=a_x$.  @HorribleATMath

Comment: Since one and only one measure $\mu\to \{a_x\}_{x\in X}$(injection) and for every $\{a_x\}_{x\in X}\in X^{[0,\infty]}$ we can define a measure $\mu(A)=\sum\limits_{x\in X}a_x 1_A(x)$ which satisfies all the given properties and has it so that $\mu \to \{a_x\}_{x\in X}$ (surjection). We have found a bijective map.